# How can I build only TensorFlow lite and not all TensorFlow from source?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use edgetpu USB accelerator with Intel ATOM single board computer and C++ API for real-time inference.

C++ API for edgetpu is based on TensorFlow lite C++ API. I need to include header files from tensorflow/lite directory (e.g. tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h).

My question is can I build tensorflow only with Lite (not other operations used for training )? if yes, how can I do it?

Because installing everything will take long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a Linux-based system, the following instruction should work:

- Clone the repository, then checkout to the stable release (currently `r1.14`):

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
  git checkout r1.14
  cd tensorflow
  ```
- Download dependencies:

  ```
  ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh
  ```
- Build it (by default it builds a Linux library, there are other options as well for other platforms):

  ```
  make -f ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/Makefile
  ```
- Now, you'll need to link the built library in your project, add this to your makefile:

  ```
  TENSORFLOW_PATH = path/to/tensorflow/
  TFLITE_MAKE_PATH = $(TENSORFLOW_PATH)/tensorflow/lite/tools/make
  CLAGS += \
      -L$(TFLITE_MAKE_PATH)/gen/linux_x86_64/obj \
      -L$(TFLITE_MAKE_PATH)/gen/linux_x86_64/lib/ \
      -ltensorflow-lite -ldl
  ```

Answer (score 1):

What you need a standalone build that is out of tensorflow repo. I have [tensorflow lite project](https://github.com/milinddeore/TfLite-Standalone-build-Linux-MacOS) that may help you, you need to cross compile it for respective platform type.